# Como ler uma String de array em Ionic/AngularJs ou Javascript e passar para diretivas?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2, ionic3

Passei parâmetros para outro TS com:

```
console.log('Data', navParams.get('sessoes'));
```

Que me mostra este resultado:

```
{data: "2018-09-11", weight: "200", sessoes: "20", repeticoes: "2", notas: "teste"}
```

Desta forma a seguir, consigo pegar cada um dos campos do Array:

```
var object = navParams.get('sessoes');    
      console.log(object["data"]);
      console.log(object["weight"]);
      console.log(object["sessoes"]);
      console.log(object["repeticoes"]);
      console.log(object["notas"]);
```

Agora preciso pegar esses dados para serem mostrados num formulário que tem `[(ngModel)]="sessao.data", [(ngModel)]="sessao.weight", [(ngModel)]="sessao.sessoes"`, etc...

Como colocar estes objetos numa diretiva ngModel para meu formulário Ionic/Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um objeto dentro da classe chamado sessao ou crie e faça um extend de uma interface

Depois passe esse objeto criado dentro do seu metodo para receber os dados do array

```
 sessao = {data: '', weight: '', sessoes: '', repeticoes: 'repeticoes', notas: ''}

      constructor() {
        let object = navParams.get('sessoes');    
        this.sessao.data = object["data"];
        this.sessao.weight = object["weight"];
        this.sessao.sessoes = object["sessoes"];
        this.sessao.repeticoes = object["repeticoes"];
        this.sessao.notas = object["notas"];
  }
```